# display:block preventing font size change in ASP.NET menu

Tags: asp.net, css

I use ASP.NET menu control in my VS2010 web app, I had a problem in dynamic menu items click-able area, so I used style=display:block and now it is OK, but unfortunately my dynamic menu items font size cannot be changed now!! before using display:block they were OK (large) but now they are displayed smaller and I cannot change their size, I've used font-size:large in my style, and also set font-size="large" in control tags but there is still no luck! what is going wrong here? how can I have both things right?

I use cssstyle="myStyle" in DynamicMenuItemStyle, and when I remove my cssstyle, font changes are performed!

this is my menu:
...

```
                                        <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5" Font-Size="XX-Large" CssClass="MenuFullClick" />
                                    <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#E6C679" Font-Size="XX-Large" Width="230px" />
                                    <DynamicHoverStyle Font-Size="XX-Large" Width="230px" />
```

and this my CSS:

```
        .MenuFullClick
    {
         display: block;
         color:White;
         Height:40px;
         Width:230px;
         font-size:xx-large;
    }
```

my final rendered HTML is like this:
...

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="Menu1n6">
        <td><table class="MenuFullClick Menu1_4" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="Menu1_1 MenuFullClick Menu1_3" href="products.aspx?id=1" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">انواع دستمال کاغذی</a></td><td style="width:0;"><img src="Images/arrow.png" alt="Expand انواع دستمال کاغذی" style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="Menu1n7">
        <td><table class="MenuFullClick Menu1_4" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="Menu1_1 MenuFullClick Menu1_3" href="pr1.aspx?catcode=9" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">پوشک بچه</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td>
```

thanks

Comment: you better of posting some css and html. did you try to empty your cache in your browser? You better of deleting this question

Comment: I've added my html and CSS, I've tested this page in several browsers and result is still the same

Comment: no, there problem is persists, I think it is because of cssstyle, when I remove it, font size is applied, but when I use cssstyle, my font is showed small, no matter what display type I use

Comment: how does your output html look? that is rendred in your browser

Comment: thanks Dejan, I've added some lines of my final rendered HTML in my question

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late answer, at work.

your link has `style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;"`

so the `font-size:1em;` sets the font-size for you. You should remove the `font-size` from `DynamicHoverStyle` and just have it on `css` class.

Comment: I did what you said, removed font-size tag from DynamicHoverStyle but there is no difference still, I use firefox, but other browsers look the same.

Comment: try changing your `font-size: xx-large`;` to `font-size: 24px !important;`

Comment: the 24px on the `font-size` is just so you can se the changes better.. change it to what ever after.